# How to use an `<a>` link tag to submit form in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to get the selected option in this form from the other side when clicking link.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(x)">
    <input type="radio" id="radioset3" name="radioset" [checked]="x==0">
    <input type="radio" id="radioset2" name="radioset" >
    <input type="radio" id="radioset1" name="radioset" >

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="flightdetails"><span><i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Flight Details</a>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

Css styled button did my job. I'm not good with css. That's why I was thinking about `a` tag.

Comment: add a `(click)` method to the same

Comment: Links are not designed to submit forms. Submit buttons are. Use a submit button! (Use CSS if you don't like the way it looks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `(click)="..."` handler can be used to submit the form

```
<a (click)="myFormSubmitHandler()" href="javascript:void(0)" class="flightdetails"><span><i class="fa fa-suitcase" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Flight Details</a>
```

In the click handler send a post request to the server using the `Http` or `HttpClient` module.